# Bug? GraphicsGrid with Item Elements

Tags: graphics, bugs, grid-layouts

Is there a bug in the GraphicsGrid routines such that it no longer handles Item elements?  There are a couple examples in the GraphicsGrid documentation (under the FrameStyles section) that give errors when I run them on 12.3.1 on Linux and 13.0 on Windows.

Is this a known bug?  Is it something I'm doing?  I'm not able to find anything about it.

Beyond the documentations examples, the following simple example gives an error (GraphicsGrid`GraphicsGridDump`FramePart is not a graphics directive)

```
GraphicsGrid[Table[Item[Text[ii jj]], {ii, 10}, {jj, 10}]]
```

If it's a bug, are their suggestions for work-arounds?

Comment: yes, looks like a bug to me. Please report to WRI.

Comment: As for a workaround, if you replace `Item` with `Graphics`, then the code does not produce errors for me but I am not on 13.